# Anyway to get Flash player to stop showing me everyone else's errors?

Tags: flash, flash-player

I have to have the debugger version of Flash player installed because I develop Flash apps.

Because of this, a huge percentage of the sites I visit constantly displaying annoying error pop up messages for their Flash apps.

It is extremely annoying. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: what exactly can you do with the debug version of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is use the non-debugger version of Flash Player.
Try using a different browser that has the normal Flash Player installed. I use Chrome for all normal browsing, while Firefox has the debugger version for when I want to see the debug errors.